# Typescript function with keyof doesn't accept object key value as valid keyof

Tags: typescript

I have a simple function that uses the `keyof` feature:

```
interface B {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

function test(key: keyof B) {}

const c = {
  age: 'age'
}

test(c.age);
```

The issue with the above code is that typescript throws an error that `type string is not assignable to keyof B`.

So what is the point of the `keyof` feature if it's not working with object key value? I don't want to add `as keyof B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that typescript does not infer by default literal types for object properties (even if they are `const`).

You can get around this by using a type assertion to the string literal type:

```
const c = {
  age: 'age' as 'age'
}

test(c.age);
```

Or of you want to infer string literal types for all properties of an object you can use a function (I use a iffe here but it can be a separate function)

```
const c = (<V extends string,  T extends Record<string, V>>(o: T) => o)({
  age: 'age'
});

test(c.age);
```

Or in 3.4 (not yet released) you can use a `as const` assertion on the object:

```
const c = {
  age: 'age'
} as const

test(c.age);
```

Comment: I don't think that would work, either. The type assertion needs to be at the level of the object, not of the value you give it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha works just fine: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgELIN4ChnJHAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4dk5qS8BXAgI2noF8ssYrEAjDAA9iGSQKACgDWEAJ6kFisTDQBKTHywIJFZAmQBeTAyYsA5JauMyyG8ytZd0sDIQA6S5tpA

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I generally test my code before posting, but it's good to keep a sharp lookout and question everything :)

Comment: Thanks, but do you think it's normal that we need to wrap code in functions just for typing?

Comment: @undefined It is what it is ... `as const` in the next version removesthe need for the function in 99% of cases, but it does make the object readonly. The perf impact of the function if you don't need to call it in perf critical code is probably negligible.

Comment: @undefined The more common case is that you have an object and are allowed to change properties on it (rather than you have an object and must not modify it).

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm disappointed by this feature. It limits you.

Comment: @undefined :)) welcome to typescript, some disappointment guaranteed :P

Comment: @undefined it's not a "feature", but rather an unfortunate side effect of one of the most useful features of the language. In almost all cases typescript's inference is excellent but sometimes you need to be more explicit than you'd like. I wouldn't let you turn this off TypeScript, you can do some awesome stuff with `keyof` especially when working with generics

Comment: Thanks @RobbieMilejczak

Comment: Here is a great article on look up types, which is in my opinion the best use of `keyof`: https://alexjover.com/blog/typescript-lookup-types-type-safe-properties/

Answer (score 2):

`c.age` will be a string because of the implicit typing (`c` will be of type `{age:string}`). You can define the type for c.age to be `keyof B`. This will also restrict you in assigning other values to the `age` property and use them accidentaly.

```
interface B {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

function test(key: keyof B) { }

const c: { age: keyof B } = {
  age: 'age'
}

test(c.age);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that TypeScript infers `c` to be of type `{age: string;}`, and not `{age: 'age';}`.

Had it inferred the latter, instead of the former, you wouldn't have been able to change `c.age` like so:

```
const c = { age: 'age' }
c.age = 'somethingElse';
```

Had you called it with the literal `'age'` directly, it would have worked as advertised.

You can override TypeScript inference with a proper type like so:

```
const c: {age: 'age'} = {
  age: 'age',
};
```

And that would both make the type error disappear, and enforce that you do not assign anything to `c.age` other than the literal string `'age'`.